# Defining a constant in Java

Tags: java, constants

```
        public enum Categories {
        GENERAL, LIGHTS, EFFECTS, INTERACTIVE, UI("UI"), OPTIMIZATIONS, PARSERS, ANIMATION, MATERIALS, ABOUT;

        private String name;

        Categories() {
            name = toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + name.substring(1, name.length());
        }

        Categories(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }
```

Inside the enumeration the first line starting with "GENERAL, EFFECTS" I am wondering what those are? Especially UI("UI"). Are those meant to be constants? Why does UI("UI") have ( and ) when the rest of them don't?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you done your studies on enums before asking this?

Comment: I wan't quite sure that was what I needed to be studying. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum Categories {
    GENERAL, LIGHTS, EFFECTS, INTERACTIVE, UI("UI"), ...
```

These represent the `Enum` constants accessible by qualifying them with the class name as

```
Categories.GENERAL, Categories.LIGHTS, Categories.UI, ...
```

`Enums` behave a lot like a class except that they are meant for representing constants. So, they can have constructors and fields as well. While `GENERAL` used the no-argument constructor

```
Categories() {
    name = toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) +
           name.substring(1, name.length());
}
```

`UI("UI")` used the other overloaded constructor (since it passed a matching string argument)

```
Categories(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Just like a class, this `Enum` defines a member field as well

```
private String name;
```

which can be accessed through the public getter method as

```
Categories.UI.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not constants per se, it's enum values.

The UI enum is calling the constructor with the string parameter with the value "UI". If you don't pass "UI" the value would be "Ui" instead since the parameterless constructor would be called.